# With dropbox API is it possible to generate a public link?

Tags: stream, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I'm just wondering if it would be possible to generate a public link to dropbox content with the API?

I'm asking this because I'm looking to upload videos from dropbox to a remote server and I want to avoid to copy the video on my local server before to upload it on the remote server.

The idea would be to open a stream directly from dropbox to upload the video on the remote server. Would this be possible ?

Cheers,

Maxime

Comment: why there was a negative vote? I fixed it, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't have sharing features and you can't generate a public link using it. The only way to generate a public link is to do it manually.